# Solving for the digits in WHITE+WATER=PICNIC

Tags: arithmetic, cryptarithm

I'm writing solutions for students who are taking a competition exam and I took problems from old [purple comet](https://purplecomet.org/resource/oldcontests) competition problems. This problem is the last one from the 2004 middle school contest and says:

> In the addition problem WHITE+WATER=PICNIC each distinct letter represents a different digit. Find the number represented by the answer PICNIC.

I have looked for solutions online and their answers have been insufficient; usually stating the only possibilities for WHITE and WATER (of which there are only two) and then giving what PICNIC must be.

I have tried my hand at this problem using strategies for solving cryptoarithmetic puzzles. I started with recognizing that P is 1 and then working with the W being at least 5, but this has always devolved into a myriad of cases. This is a problem intended for middle school students so I'm a doubtful that the intended solution is to check so many cases.

Is there some insight for this puzzle to better organize the cases?

Comment: Can you show your work? EG Doing at least the case that leads to a solution.

Comment: The folks at [Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com) may have some insights on strategy.

Comment: Since you know the answer, please include it in the question; this may allow people to work backwards to find a "good" path to it. Also, include the work you did with the myriad of cases, so that people don't waste time duplicating all of the effort that you believe shouldn't be necessary. (It's no fun devising/composing/formatting/illustrating a comprehensive and comprehensible answer to a question, only to have the asker respond "Yeah, that's how I did it; I want to see a better way.") ... Good luck!

Comment: Missing information: what system? Hexadezimal, decimal, else...

Answer (score 1):

I tried and failed. Below is my strategy:

---

We are now solving the following digit puzzle:

$$
\begin{array} 
\\           &   & W & H & I & T & E
\\        +) &   & W & A & T & E & R
\\ \hline    & P & I & C & N & I & C
\end{array}
$$

As usual, we assume that $P \neq 0$. Since $W \le 9$ and $9 + 9 = 18$, we immediately see that $P = 1$.

$I \ge 0$, so $2 W \ge 10$; hence, we derive that $W \ge 5$.

- If $W = 9$, then $2 W = 18$, so $I = 8$ since $I \neq W$;
- if $W = 8$, then $2 W = 16$, so $I \in \{ 6, 7 \}$;
- if $W = 7$, then $2 W = 14$, so $I \in \{ 4, 5 \}$;
- if $W = 6$, then $2 W = 12$, so $I \in \{ 2, 3 \}$;
- if $W = 5$, then $2 W = 10$, so $I = 0$. $I \neq 1$ since $I \neq P$.

Now, we have got many possibilities.

We want to narrow down our search for the solution. To this end, we look at some different digits. If $T + E = I$ and $I + T = N$, then $2 T + E = N$. Since $T \neq 0$ (otherwise, $E = N$; this is not allowed) and $E \neq 0$ (otherwise, $T = I$), we know that $T \ge 1$ and that $E \ge 1$. But remember that $P = 1$.

So $T \ge 2$ and $E \ge 2$. Since $T \neq E$, $N \ge 7$.

- If $N = 7$, then $T = 2$ (if $T = 3$, then $E = 1$). So $E = 3$; accordingly, $I = 5$. But then $W = 7$; this is not allowed.
- If $N = 8$, then $T \in \{ 2, 3 \}$ (if $T = 4$, then $E = 0$). If $T = 2$, then $E = 4$, so $I = 6$, but then $W = 8$. If $T = 3$, then $E = 2$, so $I = 5$ and $W = 7$.
- If $N = 9$, then $T \in \{ 2, 3 \}$ (if $T = 4$, then $E = 1$). If $T = 2$, then $E = 5$, so $I = 7$ and $W = 8$. If $T = 3$, then $E = 3$; this is obviously not allowed.

So, in summary, if $T + E = I$ and $I + T = N$, we have the following cases:

- If $N = 8$, then $T = 3$, $E = 2$, $I = 5$, and $W = 7$. Remember that $P = 1$. So we are left with $\{ 0, 4, 6, 9 \}$, which is our search space. $2 + R = C$. Since $R \neq 0$ (otherwise, $C = E$; this is not allowed), $R \neq 6$ (otherwise, $C = N$), and $R \neq 9$ (since $C \le 9$), we are left with only one possibility: $R = 4$. If so, then $C = 6$; this seems good.
- If $N = 9$, then $T = 2$, $E = 5$, $I = 7$, and $W = 8$. Again, $P = 1$. So our search space is $\{ 0, 3, 4, 6 \}$. $5 + R = C$, so $R \neq 0$ (otherwise, $C = E$), $R \neq 3$ (otherwise, $C = W$), $R \neq 4$ (otherwise, $C = N$), and $R \neq 6$ (since $C \le 9$). But then, we have effectively rejected all possible digits. So $N \neq 9$.

In summary, $N = 8$. Our remaining search space is $\{ 0, 9 \}$.

If $T + E = I$ and $I + T = N$, then, since $\left( 10 + I \right) - 2 W = 1$, we need $H + A \ge 10$. But $9 + 0 < 10$. Oh, no! So

- $T + E \neq I$ or
- $I + T \neq N$.

I am stopping here as I believe there is a very smart way, much, much more efficient. I am posting this just for others to know that my strategy probabily wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{array} 
\\           &   & W & H & I & T & E
\\        +) &   & W & A & T & E & R
\\ \hline    & P & I & C & N & I & C
\end{array}
$$

All $10$ digits are represented, so let's figure out where $0$ is first. Obviously, $W$ and $P$ are out and none of $T,E,R,I,H,A$ can be $0.$ So there are two cases.

First, let $C = 0.$ Then $E+R=10$ and $T+E+1 = I$ or $10+I.$ If the former, then $I\geq 1+2+3=6$ and thus $W\geq 8.$ If $I=6,$ then it forces $W=8$ but that contradicts the carryover from $C = 0.$ If $I=7,$ then $W=8.$ Now we have $T,E = \{2,4\}$ and $E,R = \{4,6\}$ due to $1,8,7$ having already been chosen. Therefore, $E=4, T=2,R=6$ and $N = I+T = 7+2=9.$ The only remaining digits are $3$ and $5$ and that won't satisfy $5+3 = 10.$

Moving on, if $I=8,$ then $W = 9$ but that again contradicts the carryover from the preceding $C = 0.$ $I=9$ is impossible as that would force $W = I= 9.$ Therefore $C\neq 0.$

The only other case is $N = 0$ and note that $W\neq 5$ for otherwise it implies $P=I=1.$ If $W=9,$ then $I=8$ and since $N=0,$ this means  $T=2.$ If $T=2$, $E = I-T = 6.$ The remaining digits are $\{3,4,5,7\} = \{R,C,H,A\}.$ But $6+R = C$ implies $R=7$ which contradicts $T+E=2+6=8$ that did not have carryover.

Assume, $W=8$ and so $I\in\{6,7\}.$ If $I=6,$ then there was no carryover there and $H+A+1=C$, due to carrover from $N=0.$ Since $C\leq 1+2+3 = 6$ and $6,8$ are already taken, we have either $C = 9$ or $C = 7.$ If former, then $E+R = C=9$ with no carryover and that implies $T+E = I = 6.$ If not, then $T+E = 16$ but $C = 9$ is already taken. This implies $T=4\implies E=2\implies R=7.$ This leaves $H,A = \{5,3\}$, but that satisfies $H+A+1 = 9.$ Therefore one solution seems to be:
$$
\begin{array} 
\\           &   & 8 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 2
\\        +) &   & 8 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 7
\\ \hline    & 1 & 6 & 9 & 0 & 6 & 9
\end{array}
$$.
You can exchange $H,A$ to get another but PICNIC stays the same. Honestly, the remaining cases can be checked similarly to exhaust all cases, which are $I=6$ and $C=7$ remaining from $W=8.$ Then there are two cases $W = 6,7$, having ruled out $W = 5,8,9$ just now.

Comment: E,R can't be 0, but why  can't one of  T,I,H,A be 0?

Comment: what happens if $T = 0$ for example ?

Comment: You conclude that $C\neq 0$, but you did not explore the $T+E+1=10+I$ case. Also, in agreement with @miracle173, I think that the case of $T$, $I$, $H$, and $A$ not being $0$ is not that obvious.

Comment: You would also miss the case $I=7$ with $W=8$, and you probably mean $C \geq 1+2+3=6$ instead of $\leq$.

Comment: @jorisperrenet T!=0. there must be a carry when adding E+R and a Cary when adding this carry to T+E and so T=0 And E=9, but then I=0. But the for remaining I don’t see why they can’t be 0

Comment: @dezdichado and what happens if I,H or A  is 0?

Comment: yeah both are right - more details needed. But the solution will be probably become twice longer, so I'd rather if someone else posts a cleverer answer and get accepted.